# Thinkpad L14 not working with Dell Monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, thinkpad

I'm using a Thinkpad L14 Gen (Mesa Intel® Graphics ~ADL GT2~) with Ubuntu 22.04 and an external Dell monitor with an HDMI to VGA converter (Ugreen). When using the "Join Displays" or "Mirror" options, the external monitor shows blurry and distorted images.

[image: see picture in the link].

These flaws decrease but are still present when changing to the "Single Display" option and using the external monitor.

I've checked for additional drivers to install but the "Software & Updates" application shows the message "No additional drivers available". How can I fix this?

Note: Every display mode works correctly with another laptop using the same monitor and VGA cable, with and without the HDMI to VGA adapter.